# Mongoose-Like alternative for Neo4J

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I am starting out on Neo4J and so far in their docs, there has been no mention of mapping the query results to something like a Model as done by [Mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose).

Usually in MongoDB if I wish to represent a User model in my database I can represent that with the help of Mongoose using the following schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: String,
        email:String
    });
```

Is there a [Mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose) equivalent package for interacting with Neo4J to achieve the above Schema-like representation or is the current Modeless flow the only way out?

Answer (score 0):

There is one such OGM, known as `neode`, came out recently. I haven't used it, but you can definitely give it a try.

Here is the [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neode).